# How do I display a custom field under profile name in WoWonder Feed like LinkedIn?

Tags: php, mysql, custom-backend

Wowonder is a PHP script from codecanyon.net, It is a social network script.

I want to add a Workplace description below the profile which is displayed publicly on the news feed after every activity like it is on Linkedin :

[image: Profile Screenshot How I need.]

While this is the scenario now :

[image: This is How it looks now.]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I am actually not familiar with this, can you find by inspecting element from chrome. website is http://demo.wowonder.com

Comment: Just click "edit" under the tags and [**type in relevant code**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try to format it properly using the sidebar on the right of your screen.